# Could not able to run multiple UPDATE queries inside foreach - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a array.

```
$arr = 
Array
(
    [] => save
    [1] => 
    [2] => y786
    [5] => m987
    [23] =>
    [3] => g666
)
```

And i have written an UPDATE query inside foreach.

```
foreach($arr AS  $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($key) && !empty($value)) //to chk empty key(for save) and to chk empty values
  {
    $sql = "UPDATE tablename SET code='$value' WHERE id='$key'";
    //execute query
  } 
}
```

So my update query is running only ONE time. It will check for 'non-empty' key and 'non-empty' value.

In my above array only first pair. i,e `[2] => y786` will be executed. How do i run my update queries for all 'non-empty' keys and 'non-empty' values.

EDIT - Basically i need to run my UPDATE query neglecting my first index and neglecting my all empty values. In my above array i need to have 3 UPDATE queries for the keys 2,5,3 at a time.

Comment: The keys aren't empty!?!

Comment: If $key is empty then there is no need to check for empty $value

Comment: Provide the complete code. Perhaps you are over-writing the `$arr` inside the loop somewhere.

Comment: empty key to check my first index..  [] => save

Comment: Don't see why your code should execute only once

Comment: The question is clear, but as @AbhikChakraborty pointed out, the code you show is correct, the mistake must be somewhere in the code you commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
    $arr = 
Array
(
    '' => 'save',
    1 => '',
    2 => 'y786',
    5 => 'm987',
    23 =>'',
    3 => 'g666'
);

foreach($arr AS  $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($key) && !empty($value)) //to chk empty key(for save) and to chk empty values
  {
    $sql = "UPDATE tablename SET code='$value' WHERE id='$key'";
    //execute query
    echo $sql.'<br/>';
  } 
}
```